# What tag should be used for short text like "back to top" , "Read more" etc?

Tags: xhtml, semantics, web-standards, semantic-markup

What tag should be used for short text like.

**Back to top**

**Read more**

is `<p>` appropirate or something else should be use. because these are not paragraph.

Which is more semantic

```
<p><a href="#mainWrapper">Back to top</a></p>
```

or

```
<a href="#mainWrapper">Back to top</a>
```

or

```
<div><a href="#mainWrapper">Back to top</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should use the anchor `<a>` tag.

Nesting an `<a>` inside a `<p>` is perfectly valid, but in general the `<p>` should be reserved for paragraphs of text. Since yours is just a link, the `<a>` tag alone will probably be the most recommended.

If you want your link to appear as a block element, simply style it with `display: block;`. The fact that the `<a>` tag is normally displayed inline is only because it is its default style.

Comment: It's perfectly legal to use `<a>` inside `<p>`, and done all over the world. But using the `<p>` is only justified if you really want/need a paragraph-styled block. There's no reason to imprison free-standing, innocent text in `<p>` if it's not a para.

Answer (score 2):

Anchor tag

```
<a href="#">Back to top</a>

<a href="#">Read more</a>
```

You can embed an anchor tag inside a block element. So something like this

```
<p><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
```

Comment: You can embed an anchor tag inside any block element.

Comment: but i need this in seperate line and <a> is inline

Comment: You can use the CSS style: `display: block;`

Comment: `a.back { display:block;}` will fix that for you, if you give the `a` a class of 'back'.

Comment: is it not against web standarss to change disply style any element through css while origionally has diffent display property in html specifiction?

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements must be enclosed inside block level elements, so this is the basic approach:

```
<p><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
```

Usually though the `<a>` element is already inside a `<div>` tag so the `<p>` isn't absolutely necessary but it is more semantically correct – it's still a paragraph of text even if there's only a few words in it.

Answer (score 0):

<s>There's no obvious semantic tag for such.</s>

- Perhaps you don't really need a tag there at all! Please check for this case.
- If your "short texts" are links, then you obviously need `<a href=`. If you need a CSS style for the text, you can put it into the `a` tag too.

<s>* If you need a tag for structuring only or to hang CSS styles from, then use `<span>`.</s>

Comment: u suggested <a> and <span> both are inline. so both will follow float direction of above element

Comment: You can style an `a` like you can style a `span` - the extra tag is unnecessary.

Comment: @Jitendra and Skilldrick: You both misunderstood my answer. It's not clear to me from the question that the "short texts" from the question are really meant to be links. The content of these texts hints they're links, but the OP isn't saying. If not, then `a` would not be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. My answer updated accordingly. But it's saying mostly what everybody else was saying already.

Comment: @carl now see my first comment

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot understand from your question what you want or what your problem (if any) is.